# "Error 7: Hardlock not found" when starting CANape from command line via Jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, canape

Trying to launch Vector CANape via the command line canape32 command, and it works perfectly in the windows command prompt. When attempting to run a windows batch command in our Jenkins multibranch pipeline to do the same thing, it successfully loads the remote client DLL file and then gets stops on "Error 7: Hardlock not found." This error persists in a freestyle project as well, any clues as to what the difference in the environments is? I would expect since it runs the canape32 command just like in the regular command prompt it would work just fine, but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This is a due to Jenkins redirecting the consule output.  When using Vector's ASAP2 Toolset instead of CANape to generate A2L files you can disable the output via the INI files so this doesn't occur.